Need Help Reducing OpenAI API [Python] Costs: Here's My Code
I then call like 500 times the get_category_and_subcategory function.. It cost me like 60$ which is too much for this type of job. Am I doing something wrong and what could be improved?
It seems my problem is that the category_and_subcategory is huge, that seems to be causing the biggest cost, context tokens.. I don't know how to reduce this cost.
def get_chatgpt_response(prompt):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4o",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ],
        temperature=0.1,  # Adjust the temperature for creativity
        top_p=0.1,
        response_format={"type": "json_object"}
    )
    return response.choices[0].message.content

def get_category_and_subcategory(title, description, prompt, category_and_subcategory):
    product = {'title': title, 'description': description}
    response = get_chatgpt_response(prompt.format(json.dumps(product, ensure_ascii=False),
                                                  json.dumps(category_and_subcategory, ensure_ascii=False)))
    response = json.loads(response)
    category, subcategory = response['category'], response['subcategory']
    return category.strip(), subcategory.strip()

Here is my prompt
prompt = """
You are given product details and a dictionary of possible categories and subcategories. Your task is to categorize the product into the most appropriate category and subcategory based on these details.

Product:

    {}

Choose the exact names of the Categories and Subcategories from the provided options:

    {}

Ensure your response uses the exact names from the options provided. Format your response as JSON: `{{"category": "category", "subcategory": "subcategory"}}` and nothing else. Do not deviate from the provided options.
"""



title = "Sample Product"
description = "This is a sample product description."
category_and_subcategory = {
    "Electronics": ["Mobile Phones", "Laptops"],
    "Home Appliances": ["Refrigerators", "Washing Machines"]
}

category, subcategory = get_category_and_subcategory(title, description, category_and_subcategory)
print(f"Category: {category}, Subcategory: {subcategory}")


It looks like you are not providing any actual data as inputs. But that code is also missing.

The categories and subcategories are too big, the product is just any random title product and any random title description

Consider how many Mobile Phones, Laptops, Refrigerators and Washing Machines there could be in the world, and you can see why this question is expensive. You just need to narrow your search criteria to a specific product and manufacturer, or marketplace.

I found a solution, instead of my prompt sending one product I sent multiple products to classify (mostly like 100) at once. It works.

Give an example of the input , please

You have to  write instruction for AI as to what type of response you want.I think it is not enough to make him understand. because it doesn’t have much regard for your instructions or wishes. You have to tell it excessively why if it doesn’t comply, errors and crashes will happen. Here is my instruction might help you.
Please convert the following text into a JSON format for a survey with the following structure. I need to use your responses for my survey system, so it is absolutely crucial that there are no duplicate questions in the final file. Carefully review the chat history and ensure that no questions are repeated.

Additionally, I will be combining all of your responses later. Therefore, it is essential that you remove the initial [ and final ] from each response and add a comma ',' immediately after the closing brace at the end of each response. Failure to do so will result in errors in my system. Your meticulous attention to these details is imperative for the successful integration of this survey data.

Furthermore, ensure that each response is generated within the maximum token limit. It is critical that you adhere to this constraint to avoid truncation or errors in processing.

If you could see any descriptions, please put descriptions in the others.Also do not split each questions into 2 or more, otherwise survey system will make 2 same questions.


{{
    "question_number": "<number>",
    "question_text": "<question_content>",
    "answer_type": "<single_choice|multiple_choice|matrix_single_choice|matrix_multiple_choice|free_single_text|free_multiple_text>",
    "options": [
        {{
            "option_number": "<number>",
            "option_text": "<text>"
        }}
    ],
    "others": "<other information>"
}}

Here is the text to convert:

{chunk}

Ensure the format is correct, paying attention to curly brackets and commas especially last comma every response.


Sorry, it seems my problem is that the category_and_subcategory is huge, that seems to be causing the biggest cost, context tokens.. I don't know how to reduce this cost.
I have included a better example.
